# Sed / awk script to correct illegal characters from XML (ampersand)

Tags: xml, sed, awk, bash

For parsing an invalid XML file, having either unencoded, illegal characters (ampersands in my case):

```
<url>http://example.com?param1=bad&param2=ampersand</url>
```

and encoded ones

```
<description> The good, the bad &amp; the ugly </description>
```

Please post an example with a sed/awk script that can encode the illegal characters.

Comment: Why is the XML generator producing invalid XML in the first place?

Comment: It's not generated by me, I'm only parsing an external service that is returning invalid XML. Since the XML is very big (tens of MB), I can afford to save it on disk and preparse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tidy -m -xml <your-xml-file>
```

Comment: what package provides `tidy`?

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested, but you could cheat by converting all the valid ones back to their original form then doing the conversion back again.

For example, if you only had to worry about ampersands, you could do something similar to:

`sed 's/&amp;/&/g' | sed 's/&/&amp;/g'`

Of course, you can do it a lot cleaner and their will be better solutions, but some rest is calling me and I'm sure you can work it out from here.

Comment: That may not accomplish what you think. From the sed man page: "An ampersand (&) appearing in the replacement [of the s/// command]
will be replaced  by the string matching the RE. The special meaning of & in this context can be suppressed by preceding  it by backslash." -- so `s/&amp;/&/g` will actually change nothing.  Did you mean `s/&amp;/\&/g`?